# Does the pointclass of universally Baire sets always have the uniformization property?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, descriptive-set-theory

A set of reals, or binary relation on the reals, etc., is called *universally Baire* if and only if every continuous preimage of it in every topological space has the property of Baire.  (There is also a useful characterization involving absolutely complementing pairs of trees.)

A pointclass $\Gamma$ is said to have the *uniformization property* if and only if for every binary relation $R \in \Gamma$ there is a function $f \in \Gamma$ such that $f \subset R$ and the domain of $f$ equals the domain of $R$.  (Here we identify a function with its graph.)

Steel proved that if there is a proper class of Woodin cardinals, then the pointclass of universally Baire sets has the uniformization property.

Is the conclusion of Steel's theorem provable in ZFC?  I would guess not, but I have not been able to come up with a counterexample.  In particular, I do not know whether or not it holds in $L$.